# Wrap content with a div after each h2

Tags: jquery

Anyone can give me some ideas how can i wrap any content with a `<div>` after each `<h2>` tag and give it a unique id, done with jquery?

Im trying to do this:

```
<h2>Test</h2>
 <div id="wrap_1"> // This is the wrapper im trying to add
   <p>Bla bla</p>
   <p>More Bla bla</p>
 </div>
<h2>Another test</h2>
 <div id="wrap_2"> // This is the wrapper im trying to add
   <p>Bla bla</p>
   <p>More Bla bla</p>
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('h2').each(function(index) { 
    $(this).nextUntil('h2').wrapAll('<div id="wrap' + index + '"></div>');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/xsg8P/)

Comment: That works except for the first ``next()``. It shouldn't be there. @SLaks: you're skipping the ``div`` that should be added via jQuery. I created this jsfiddle with @SLaks code and my change: http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/d2aQn/

Comment: @marco: Yes; I just fixed that & made my own demo.  I had mistakenly thought that `nextUntil` included the current element.

Comment: Thank u guys! But in my test page it looks strange. He puts two divs instead of one! like this `code<div id="wrap0"><div id="wrap0"><p>TEst</p></div></div>`

Comment: @dut: What's your test page?  Are you running this code twice?

Comment: @SLaks: so strange...its the same code! i tried it on fiddle and everything id fine, but when i code it in notepad it doesnt http://jsfiddle.net/dutraveller/qgrXP/

Comment: yeah, the problem was that i called the script in the end of the body section